# Invalid account: #0 for network: sepolia - private key too long, expected 32 bytes

Tags: solidity, blockchain, hardhat-deploy

```
require('dotenv').config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");

const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.7.3",
  defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    sepolia: {
      url: API_URL,
      accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`]
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

private keys do not start with `0x`, public keys are the keys that start with `0x` in EVM chains.

You must provide a private key, not a public one.